# SQL (Postgres) fill in missing dates with values from last non empty day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with dates, product code and price.  But I have dates for business days, so it is missing weekends and holidays.  I would like to add any missing days, so that those days contain the previous non-empty price.

For example:
product_info

```
Date         prod_code  price
2019-12-12   123        17.00
2019-12-12   456        20.00
2019-12-12   789        22.00
2019-12-13   123        18.50
2019-12-13   456        21.50
2019-12-13   789        22.50
2019-12-16   123        17.00
2019-12-16   456        20.00
2019-12-16   789        22.00
```

I would like to be able to update/insert records such that the table would contain:

```
Date         prod_code  price
2019-12-12   123        17.00
2019-12-12   456        20.00
2019-12-12   789        22.00
2019-12-13   123        18.50
2019-12-13   456        21.50
2019-12-13   789        22.50
2019-12-14   123        18.50
2019-12-14   456        21.50
2019-12-14   789        22.50
2019-12-15   123        18.50
2019-12-15   456        21.50
2019-12-15   789        22.50
2019-12-16   123        17.00
2019-12-16   456        20.00
2019-12-16   789        22.00
```

From what I've searched for online, I probably will need to use a calendar table and perhaps some window functions, but Im not sure how to get started.  Would greatly appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `generate_series()` to capture the dates.  Then you can use a lateral join to fill in the data:

```
select gs.date, p.prod_code, t.price
from generate_series('2019-12-12'::date, '2019-12-19'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) cross join
     (select distinct prod_code from t) p left join lateral
     (select t.price
      from t
      where t.date <= gs.date and
            t.prod_code = p.prod_code
      order by t.date desc
      limit 1
     ) t
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: in your example above, are p and t separate tables, or is p an alias back to the t table, and thus only one actual source table plus the generate_series?

Comment: `p` is a table alias.

Comment: hmm, ok, thats what I thought.  When I run the query Im getting back
gs.prod_code does not exist.

Comment: Ah, I think it works with t.prod_code = p.prod_code, instead of t.prod_code = gs.prod_code.